# Can duct tape be used to mark neutral wires?

Tags: electrical-panel, neutral

Hello I’m in search of code requirements as they relate to the use of duct tape for marking the neutral conductor in the service panel.  My understanding is this is a code violation as duct tape is a conductor and also degrades with time but I’m not able to locate the code. Please see attached photo and provide any code specifics you might know.  Thank you!!

Comment: Is your neutral conductor not insulated? Like did they run a bare wire for neutral and cover it in duct tape? In the past Duct Tape was made with aluminized (hence the grey). Modern that is too expensive and the color is from pigments. Duct Tape (Aluminum foil) is bright and shiny, and should no where be near an electrical panel.

Comment: The neutral conductor is insulated coming in from the meter.  This is modern duct tape not the old aluminum foil type.

Comment: @J.Hirsch sadly,  "Duct "  and "Duck" are used interchangeably in the USA to refer to that cloth-backed tape that sticks to nothing but itself.    Dunno which the OP means.

Comment: Why not ask any licensed electrician what the code is in your area?   You may well not need any insulation on the neutral,  and further there's unlikely to be a need to "mark" it .

Comment: Show me the 600v insulation testing results (UL) that certifies the particular tape and I would say it is ok without that it is not safe to use on any electrical wire.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The only case I know of where neutral doesn't need insulations is a) service entrances/drops, and b) legacy use of SE type cable for dryers and ranges.  We insulate neutral for a reason!

Comment: @EdBeal I think the OP just means someone wrapped the neutral with (say, white) tape to show it was the neutral. I've always seen this done, but if the neutral was bare and wrapped in tape then... no.

Answer (score 1):

We can always go for the old chestnuts.  They're on page 1 and 2.

> **110.2 Approval.** The conductors and equipment required or permitted by this Code shall be acceptable only if approved.
>
> **110.3 Examination, Identification, Installation, and Use
>   of Equipment.**
>
> **(A) Examination.** In judging equipment, considerations
>   such as the following shall be evaluated:
>   (l) Suitability for installation and use in conformity with
>   the provisions of this Code
>   (4) Electrical insulation
>   (5) Heating effects under normal conditions of use and also
>   under abnormal conditions likely to arise in service
>
> **(B) Installation and Use.** Listed or labeled equipment
>   shall be installed and used in accordance with any instructions
>   included in the listing or labeling.
>
> **110.12 Mechanical Execution of Work.** Electrical equipment
>   shall be installed in a neat and workmanlike manner.

There's also a problem with the gray/silver color.

> **200.7(C) Circuits of 50 volts or more.**  The use of insulation
>   that is white or gray or that has three continuous white
>   stripes for other than a *neutral* for circuits of
>   50 volts or more shall be permitted only as in (l) and (2).
>   (1) If part of a cable assembly that has the insulation permanently
>   reidentified to indicate its use as a *hot* by marking tape, painting, or other
>   effective means at its termination and at each location
>   where the conductor is visible and accessible. Identification
>   shall encircle the insulation and shall be a color
>   **other than white, gray**, or green.
>   (2) [pertains to cordage only]

Comment: Page 1 and 2 of what code, applicable in what country or state or city?

Comment: @carl Witthoft , Of the National electric code article 100 is the definitions, article 110 are the requirements that is what the numbers represent most of the US and a few other countries use the NEC as a basis for there electrical code.

Comment: I enjoyed talking with our old Electricians at work. The code specific wiring they had (and they did get into it at times with the inspectors) was site/company specific. Kodak had their OWN wiring codes- which basically defined most of Rochester.

Comment: @J.Hirsch Yeah, somewhere in the Code is a rule that says, basically, "Be consistent across your whole site." E.G. Let's say you're Paisley Park (Prince's studio) and you use purple-pink-black for your 208 3phase, and purple-red-blue for your 480, that's all cool... but then don't go using purple-red-blue for a 208 circuit.

Comment: What chestnut? Which document are you citing? Which location are you answering for?

Comment: @MadsSkjern *El Nec* territory, based on the phraseology OP used and particular Code concerns OP cited.  Geolocation is my superpower :)  Seriously, UK/Euro/Philippine/AUNZ askers *don't* deliberately translate their questions into NEC idioms. The language tells the tale.